# Using C to modify response in VCL

Tags: c, varnish-vcl, varnish-4

The [varnish docs](https://varnish-cache.org/docs/trunk/users-guide/vcl-inline-c.html) say that we can include C snippets inside a VCL file, like

```
sub vcl_hash {
    C{
            int i = /* Some logic to get a number */
    }C
}
```

But now how can I use the value of the integer `i` to set a response header, or cookie

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [varnish.vcc](https://gist.github.com/CantonBolo/e3ce5d38e8d9d4ae9ad9)

And the functions:

- [VRT_SetHdr](https://gist.github.com/CantonBolo/e3ce5d38e8d9d4ae9ad9#file-varnish-vcc-L302)
- [VRT_GetHdr](https://gist.github.com/CantonBolo/e3ce5d38e8d9d4ae9ad9#file-varnish-vcc-L301)

in varnish 4 there is `ctx` variabl defined for the context (as opposed to `sp` in varnish 3 ) ([source](http://jan.bogutzki.de/Artikel/395/set-ttl-in-varnish-4.html))

example:

```
sub vcl_hash {
    C{
        const char *hash = calc_hash(...);
        const struct gethdr_s hdr = { 
            HDR_BERESP,
            "\010X-Hash:" // length prefixed string, in octal 
        };
        VRT_SetHdr(ctx, &hdr, hash, vrt_magic_string_end);
    }C
}
```

see [here for another example](https://gist.github.com/CantonBolo/e3ce5d38e8d9d4ae9ad9#file-varnish-vcc-L839)

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just use VCL?
`set resp.http.x-header = header` to set any header you wanna set.

Comment: Because I have some complex logic to get the variable using loops and conditions. I don't think we can use loops in VCL

Answer (score 0):

I'd encourage you to write a vmod directly, It'll be way more comfortable. You can find a (old but still relevant) guide here: https://info.varnish-software.com/blog/creating-a-vmod-vmod-str